# MS Access DOS Theme?

Tags: ms-access, retro-computing

I've just converted an old MS-DOS Paradox database over to MS Access 2013.
The end users don't like the new Access look so my bosses have asked me to make it look as much as possible to the old DOS application.

Is there any way to do this... Old Fonts colour schemes etc?

Comment: Are you serious? First, let's clarify this: one thing is the database and another *very different* thing is the user interface. If your database is meant to be used directly (without a UI), then why don't you convert it to a more geeky platform like MySQL (that has a CLI)?

Answer (score 5):

Seriously? Well, okay, some things you could try would include:

- use a fixed-pitch font for all controls, perhaps even an ancient (raster?) font like `System`
- set all forms to have a black background with white (or green, or even amber) text
- get rid of as many graphical elements as possible (borders, shading effects, buttons that actually look like buttons, etc.)
- size your forms so that you will get approximately 80 columns by 25 lines of text (or perhaps slightly larger if you want to go for a "Super VGA" look).
- and so on.... (you get the idea).

Good luck with this. It certainly qualifies as the strangest request I've seen here so far.

Comment: I agree with you: this is really strange (maybe not the strangest but quite close). LOL!